# Is it possible to select a custom handler by request verb?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I write a custom handler to handle requests with OPTIONS verb.

```
public class OptionsRequestHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string origin = context.Request.Headers.Get("Origin");
        context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
        context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "accept, authorization, content-type");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

And have registered this handler in web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  ......
</modules>
<handlers>
......
  <add name="OptionsHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" type="REAMS.Infrastructure.RequestHandlers.OptionsRequestHandler"/>   
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

But the handler is never selected for options requests. Is there anything wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out this problem. Because, by default, MVC framework map request to a handler by path, it is not possible to map a handler to a request by the request verb.

To do this, I will need to preempt the handler selection of MVC and implement my own module. Here is a working copy for anyone interested.

```
public class OptionsVerbModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PostRequestHandlerExecute += onPostRequestHandlerExecute;
        context.PostResolveRequestCache += onPostResolveRequestCache;
    }

    private void onPostResolveRequestCache(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (string.Equals(HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod, "OPTIONS", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.RemapHandler(new OptionsRequestHandler());
        }
    }

    private void onPostRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string origin = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Get("Origin");

        if (origin != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

What the module does is to check the verb of the request and if it is of 'OPTIONS' request, selected my customized handler in the question rather than map to MVC handler.

I do this because I find existing EnableCors for Web API is not suitable for my application needs and by using this customized process I have more control as well.